# Way(s) to Improve Performance of Streaming Video Frames

Tags: node.js, flask, video-streaming, streaming

I have this Nuxt SPA. It has two img elements, each taking a URL to a streaming endpoint (using GET). Each img element has a counter attached to it and its number is updated on every "onload" event. The endpoint is located on a Flask server and works by streaming frames (PNG images) extracted from a video file (using OpenCV) using generators, yield, and the MIME type multipart/x-mixed-replace. Basically the same to the method described in: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

It works with no issues, my problem now is performance. If there is only one stream working (one GET request, one connection), everything is fine performance-wise. But when there are two streams working in parallel (two GET requests, two incoming connections at the same time), the App struggles and it lags very hard: It freezes on displaying one frame, updating the counter. Then after a while the counter increases quickly by 100 or so and it displays a frame 100 or so frames ahead from the previous one. This happens in an alternating fashion between the 2 img elements. So element 1 will load 100 or so then freeze, then element 2 will do the same and freeze, rinse and repeat.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this? I need to improve the performance so both "streams" can run at the same time without having such insane lags.

I think that it might be the two connections competing against each other so I have been thinking of sending multiple GET requests instead. The response would be a batch (array) of let's say 100-200 frames. Then a function in the app would play the frames at 30 FPS or so. Once the array is almost empty, then it will make a new GET request for the next batch of frames. Rinse and repeat, and do it in an alternating fashion between the 2 img elements.

Do you think this will alleviate the issue? Or am I solving the wrong problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer in detail without looking at the exact HW and SW being used on the client as there are many factors, such as bandwidth, ability to run multiple threads in parallel, fetching optimisations in browsers, HW vs SW codecs etc that might affect performance.

However, one high level thing that may help, if you are able to use it for your use case, would be to try to leverage the existing optimisations that many servers and clients have for video streaming and playback.

In other words, given that your source is essentially a stream of video frames, if you can combine them into an 'actual' video stream then the browser can simply request that video stream and the server can simply serve a video.

This allows you leverage all the inbuilt mechanisms to download the video in 'chunks', using range requests and/or Adaptive Bit rate streaming.

The client will also be able to leverage existing buffering and playback mechanisms for video.

Most common laptop/desktop machines should be able to handle two parallel videos being played back at the same time so this could take away the playback pain you are seeing, at the cost of more work on the server side to package the frames into video streams.